# Google Cloud SQL - Connecting and inserting with PHP

Tags: php, database, pdo, google-cloud-sql

I'm having trouble making this work. I've read through all of the PHP "Getting Started" Documentation, and I believe I have everything set up like I'm supposed to, but I cannot get my inserts to work. I have this:

```
 <?php
echo "Hello!";

$db = new PDO('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/myApp:myInstance;charset=utf8',
  'root',
  ''
);

$name = "My Name";

 $sql = "INSERT INTO players (playerName, dateCreated) VALUES (:name, NOW())";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);

$stmt->execute();


echo "We connected!";
?>
```

I'm trying to connect to my database call "myGameDatabase" and pull from the "players" table. When I deploy this, and run example.appspot.com in the browser, I see a page that prints Hello!We connected!

So since I see the "We connected" message, this makes me believe there were no errors and it went through. I don't believe it is going through though.

Using mysql client I am able to look into the players table and I see no rows. I also just did an export of my cloud sql all databases to a cloud storage bucket and based on that it also looks like there are no rows:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `players`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `players`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `playerId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `playerName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebookId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`playerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
 *!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `players`
--

LOCK TABLES `players` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `players` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `players` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

 --
-- Current Database: `mysql`
--
```

As you can see, when it dumps the table data, there is nothing there.

**Edit:**
Also, somehwat a different topic maybe, but notice I have '' as my password. That's because whenever I set a root password in the Access Control tab, I get an error on the construction of the PDO object saying that it can't connect with root@localhost and password "myPassword". So I had to do SET password for 'root' = Password(''); Is this normal?

Comment: Are you running on App Engine? (that is, on Google server's, not your development server).

Comment: Yes I am. I edit my files, deploy, and then hit the appspot url. So I believe that means I'm running on App Engine.

Comment: Can you try wrapping your code around `try {...} catch (PDOException e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }` to see if there's an error message?

Comment: Yep. Turns out I had a spelling error in my sql.

Comment: Great!.

So, about the password thing. When you set the root password through the Cloud Console you only set it for 'root'@%. This includes all external IP connections, but does not affect 'root'@'localhost' which is how App Engine connects to Cloud SQL.